# Try to the File.listFiles() is returning null in android 11

Tags: java, android

I was creating an application to test whether File.listFiles() method is working or not. To check this I made an application and I used it there but this returning null in place of an array. This is my full code please help and I have granted all permissions for android 11

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:node="merge" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.STORAGE"
        tools:node="merge" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button deleteButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initView();
    }
    private void initView() {
        deleteButton = findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteFiles(view);
            }
        });
    }
    private void deleteFiles(View v) {
        File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/");
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] files;
            files = file.listFiles();
            int a = files.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                new File(file, files[i].getName()).delete();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) file,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/"` try `"/storage/emulated/0"` instead. And allways check for null before use. How did you grant permissions?

Comment: I tried to use "/storage/emulated/0", it can find the all folder path.
But I want to delete the files in "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/", how can I check?

Comment: Well first tell if listFiles() really returns null. Or if it returns an empty list. If it returns null you would have a NullPointerException and you did not tell you had one.

Comment: Repeat: `How did you grant permissions? ` Why dont you answer? The user can only grant permissions at runtime.

Comment: How did you grant permissions? -> I use below setting

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:node="merge" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.STORAGE"
        tools:node="merge" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

Comment: Repeat: `Well first tell if listFiles() really returns null. Or if it returns an empty list. If it returns null you would have a NullPointerException and you did not tell you had one.`  You should answer all questions!!!

Comment: It returns empty list

Comment: Indeed. It returns an empty list. `I use below setting ` Well we already saw that. But the user has to grant those permissions at runtime too. And you did not tell us if you added the code for that.

Comment: I've added below code to grant permission.
The list can return the file name now

  private void assignPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }

Comment: Please put your code in your post. Its unreadable in a comment .

Answer (score 0):

You need to get run time permision

```
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
    }
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 3);
    }
```